# MySQLWorkbench for macOS 12.7.4

Tags: mysql-workbench, macos-monterey

I downloaded and installed the latest version 8.0.36 of MySQLWorkbench for macOS. When I try to start MySQLWorkbench I get the following error:

```
You can't use this version of the
application "MySQLWorkbench"
with this version of macOS.
You have macOS 12.7.4. The application
requires macOS 13.0 or later.
```

Is there anywhere a compatibility matrix which version from the archives of MySQLWorkbench is available and working for macOS version 12 Monterey?

I tried also version 8.0.34 but without success.

Comment: same issue, I used 8.0.32 in the end

Comment: Thanks for this hint. I was able to install it but whenever I open a table it crashes.

Comment: same actually, I can open, and use DB Reverse Engineering, when I select on a table it crashes.

Answer (score 0):

Also confirming: Click Archives -> Downloaded version 8.0.32 of MySQL Workbench. It worked for me.